# no suitable constructor exists to convert from "test *" to "test", constructor,

Tags: c++, object, pointers, constructor, instance

I'm new to `c++` and I'm having difficulties with constructor and classes. So, here is my header file:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class test
{

    private:
    string name;
    int number;

public:

    test();
    test(string i,int b);
};
```

This is cpp file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;


test::test(){}

test::test(string i,int b){
    this->name=i;
    this->number=b;
}
```

now, when I try to call

```
test t=new test("rrr",8);
```

I get:

```
1   IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "test *" to "test"
```

So, whats the thing with classes having `*` in their name ( for instance, classes without .cpp file don't have asterix, all others do)? And what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

I imagine you're coming from a Java/C# background.  `t` is not a reference type here, it's a value type.  `new` returns a pointer to an object.  So you need any of the following:

```
test t = test("rrr", 8);
test t("rrr", 8);
test *t = new test("rrr", 8);
```

If you're not yet familiar with pointers, then definitely don't use the last one!  But understanding the semantics of pointers is fairly critical; I recommend reading the relevant chapter(s) in your textbook...

Comment: Nice, your answer is much better than mine :) +1

Comment: tnx a lot. u guessed right, i did programming in java and c# so im i bit struggling with c++ :) ....

Comment: @klo If you try to program C++ like you programmed Java you will make loads of mistakes. They are not very similar at all.

Comment: "I imagine you're coming from a Java" that hurted but thanks anyways lol, i was missing the * operator before my variable name

Answer (score 14):

> So, whats the thing with classes having "*" in their name ( for instance, classes without .cpp file dont have asterix, all others do)???

You definitely need to learn about pointers. `test *` and `test` are two completely different types in C++. Here's two variables with those types:

```
test t;
test* p;
```

Here, `t` has type `test`, and `p` as type `test*`. We describe `test*` as "pointer to `test`".

You can often think of a pointer as being the memory address of an object. So in `p`, since it is a pointer, we could store the memory address of `t`, which is a `test`. To get the address of an object, we use the unary `&` operator, like so:

```
test t;
test* p = &t;
```

Note that `t` *is* a `test` object. You didn't need to say `new test()`. This is where C++ differs from other languages that you might have used, like C# and Java. In the above C++ code, `t` is a `test` object.

However, you *can* create objects with `new test()`, so what's the difference?

`test t;` creates a `test` object with automatic storage duration. This means it is destroyed at the end of its scope (often the function is being declared within).

`new test()` creates a `test` object with dynamic storage duration. This means you have to destroy the object manually, otherwise you'll have a memory leak. This expression returns a pointer and so you can initialise a pointer object with it:

```
test* p = new test();
```

So now let's look at your problem:

```
test t=new test("rrr",8);
```

We now know that `new test("rrr", 8)` returns a pointer to `test` (a `test*`). However, you're trying to assign it to a `test` object. You simply can't do this. One of them is an address and the other is a `test`. Hence the compiler says "no suitable constructor exists to convert from `test *` to `test`." Makes sense now, doesn't it?

Instead, you should prefer to use automatic storage duration. Only use `new` if you really really need to. So just do:

```
test t("rrr", 8);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
T* t = new T;
//     ^^^
```

When new is used in this object construction, it denotes the creation of a pointer. What are doing is dynamically allocating memory which I'm sure you didn't mean to do. The Rather, typical stack allocated object construction is done simply like this:

```
T t;
```

Even if you had intended on creating a pointer and allocating the memory, you did it the wrong way. A pointer is created with the `*` symbol, which you lacked in your code. Secondly, when you're done using the memory you created, you must remember to `delete`/`delete[]` your code. `delete[]` is used on dynamically allocated arrays. So this is how it would look for your pointer:

```
delete t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
test t=new test("rrr",8);
```

must be

```
//  v
test* t=new test("rrr",8);
```

---

> So, whats the thing with classes having "*" in their name

`*` is used to indicate a pointer, it's not in the name of the class. But it's a big topic, so you should do some reseach on this.

Answer (score 1):

`*` is not part of the name, it's a modifier denoting, that the object is a pointer. A pointer is a variable holding address to some place in memory, where the actual object is stored. Some basics:

```
int i = 5;
int * pI = &i;
```

`int * pI` means, that you want to declare a pointer to place in memory, where an int is held. `&i` means, that you want to retrieve a pointer to variable. So now pI holds address in memory, where i is stored. Now you can *dereference* a pointer - get to value of the pointer:

```
int j = *pI;
```

Now you tell the compiler, that it should go to the address pointed to by pI and retreive its contents (since pI is a pointer to int, compiler will assume, that there's an int there).

Now, back to your example. `new` operator allocates memory dynamically for an object, so:

```
new test("rrr", 8);
```

results in allocating a memory for test class, calling its constructor with parameters "rrr" and 8 and returning a pointer to allocated memory. That's why you cannot assign it to `test` variable: new operator in this case returns a `test *`.

Try this code:

```
test * t = new test("rrr", 8);
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not define `t` as a pointer:

```
test* t=new test("rrr",8);
```

Or just

```
test t = test("rrr",8);
```